# AngularJS: Directive is not firing or working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

new in angular. so just do not understand why the below code and directive is not working. where i made the problem in code.

no item name and price is showing in page.

### few questions

what is the meaning of require: 'ngModel', ?

what is controller in directive ?

when controller option fire ?

when people declare controller option in directive ?

share the knowledge please in details ?

Html code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <ul ng-controller="MyController">

    <li my-directive price="item.price" ng-repeat="item in products">
        {{item.name}} &mdash; {{item.price}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Angular Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {

$scope.products = [
    {
        'name' : 'Xbox',
        'clearance' : true,
        'price' : 30.99,
    },
    {
        'name' : 'Xbox 360',
        'clearance' : false,
        'salesStatus' : 'old',
        'price' : 99.99,
    },
    {
        'name' : 'Xbox One',
        'salesStatus' : 'new',
        'price' : 50,
    },
    {
        'name' : 'PS2',
        'clearance' : true,
        'price' : 79.99,
    },
    {
        'name' : 'PS3',
        'salesStatus' : 'old',
        'price' : 99.99,
    },
    {
        'name' : 'PS4',
        'salesStatus' : 'new',
        'price' : 20.99,
    }
    ]
})
```

Angular Directive:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    scope: { price: '=' },
    require: 'ngModel',
    link : function(scope){
      console.log(scope.price)
      alert('scope price '+scope.price);
    },
    controller: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){
      console.log(ngModel.price);
      console.log(scope.price);
      alert('ngModel price '+scope.price);
      alert('scope price '+scope.price);
    },

    template: 'Name: {{item.name}} Address: {{item.price}}'
  }
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/6am7xd0r/1/)

Comment: Here's a funcionat example, you have errors in your parsing https://jsfiddle.net/r007/wps11eqf/  example of ng-model(not my fiddle) : http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/6zab5/.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the meaning of require: 'ngModel', ?

When you want to require controller of `another directive`. Here you are trying to call `ngModel` directive's controller.

> what is controller in directive ? when controller option fire ? when
>   people declare controller option in directive ?

`Controller` for a directive is defined in one's context, it can be injected in other directive for a `inter-directive communication`.

Here is a detailed post on the life-cycle execution of a directive, which can help your better. 
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/28/compile-pre-and-post-linking-in-angularjs.aspx

There is lots of mistakes in your fiddle you have shared, have corrected some to print the values passed from `view` to `directive` to display. 
https://jsfiddle.net/6am7xd0r/2/

Comment: good but not clear. after read all goes above of my head. it will be more helpful if some one discuss ngModel or controller use in directive with easy example because i am new in angular.